# How to separate unit test & integration test execution using maven surefire plugin?

Tags: cucumber, maven-surefire-plugin

I have unit tests written in junit & integration tests in cucumber. I am trying to separate unit test & integration test execution. i know this question already exists. I tried a lot of writings on the internet but did not help. Atm I can execute cucumber test only from IDE and not through CLI. "mvn test" command executes only unit tests and not integration test. Please help.

```
     mvn test -Dtest=RunCucumberIntegrationTest -Dcucumber.options="-tags @integration"
```

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <configuration>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/RunCucumberIntegrationTest.java</exclude>
              </excludes>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <includes>
                <include>**/RunCucumberIntegrationTest.java</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Maybe you should create two different profiles in maven for unit test and integration test. Then based on your requirement you can do the execution of any profile. If You need any example then please let me know. I will be happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample pom.xml file. I can execute any profile based on my requirement.

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.gtihub.frostyaxe</groupId>
        <artifactId>StackOverflow-61781205</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <profiles>

            <profile>
                <id>junit</id>
                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                            <dependencies>
                                <!-- Force using the latest JUnit 47 provider -->
                                <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                                    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                                </dependency>
                            </dependencies>
                            <configuration>
                                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                                <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                                <configuration>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>${project.basedir}/src/test/java/unit/testclasses/*.java</include>
                                        <exclude>${project.basedir}/src/test/java/integration/testclasses/*.java</exclude>
                                    </includes>
                                </configuration>
                            </configuration>

                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
            </profile>

            <profile>
                <id>testng</id>
                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
            </profile>

        </profiles>
    </project>
```